# Reseting admin password through PHPMyadmin fails

Tags: password, phpmyadmin, reset

Following the PHPMyAdmin instructions of [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) fails to reset my password properly.

I go into WP_Users, find my admin account, click edit, enter my password, change the dropdown to MD5, click save, but this password does not work when I try to login to WP-Admin with this username.

Confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a picture explaning how to do it
be carful and backup the database befoure any changes are done

first here is a link to md5 encoder (youll need it): [MD5 Encoder](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php)

[image: howto change password in phpMyadmin]

.
Hope this helps ;)
Cheers, Sagive.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [web-based MD5 generator](http://www.adamek.biz/md5-generator.php), and then paste  the generated MD5 value directly into phpMyAdmin without using phpMyAdmin's MD5 function. When using the generator, choose a simple password, like "temp123" to avoid any potential issues with complexity. Then once you can login to WordPress, use the Admin Panel to change ithe password back to something strong.

If that doesn't work, try the [lost password feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_the_automatic_emailer) or the [FTP method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_FTP). The lost password feature is probably the easiest. If you need to, you can use phpMyAdmin to update the e-mail address associated with the e-mail account.

Answer (score 3):

Set your admin ID and run this statement in your PhpMyAdmin

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('12345') WHERE ID=1;
```

Comment: this one helped me!
since there was no MD5 in the PhpMyAdmin interface!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the admin e-mail in the field specified above by Sagive and then retrieving it via /wp-login.php

Comment: "Password reset is not allowed for this user".  This user is the network admin.

Answer (score -1):

When in doubt, hack away.  If you are a little confused with the MD5 in the phpmyadmin you can try saving the email to a file.

1) If your site is live, this will require using FTP.  I recommend using Filezilla as it makes FTP very simple.  You will need to create an FTP user in your C-Panel if you haven't already.

2) Find the file "wp-includes\pluggable.php" and drag it to a folder.  Open the file.  I recommend opening the file in a text editor like notepad plus or sublime.

3) Hit CTRL + F to find (mac is CMD + F).  Type in "wp_mail".  Scroll down about a hundred lines until you find...

```
$phpmailer->Body = $message;
```

This should be around line 370.

4) Right below that line insert this code...

```
$f = fopen("email.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $message);
fclose($f);
```

5) Once the file is saved drag and drop it into the FTP window to upload it to the server.

6) Load the login page and click "Lost Password."  Once you click to send an email the email will be saved to "email.txt".  From there you should be able to reset everything.

7) After you have recovered your password change "wp-includes\pluggable.php" back and delete email.txt immediately!  This hack will leave your site vulnerable.  Recover your password and change it back, you'll be okay.  Forget to change it back I am not responsible.

Comment: You should never modify core on a live site

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work for me. That said, if you want to do something like this, consider creating a plugin, since all functions in wp-includes/pluggable.php are designed to be overwritten...