# I cannot log into my wordpress site with my wp-login.php

Tags: wp-admin, login

I can login into wordpress.com - but I cannot login to to my hosting wordpress site: 
http://www.hunterbaby.com.au/wp-login.php

When I try to reset password it only recognises my wordpress username - but not my existing emails that are linked with my wordpress account? So I'm unable to send a reset password link.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you might have the wrong email set up in your wordpress installation or you might have got hacked?.. (hope not) anyhow i have already
answered as to how to change your password via the database.

You should already check what email is setup when vieweing the database.

Here is my original answer:
[Resetting password via phpMyadmin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47556/7990)

Answer (score 0):

There are [multiple ways to reset your password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) (apart from what Sagive already mentioned).

Let me share how to reset the password using cPanel's **File Manager**. It works, if you are the (only or first) admin user...

- Login to your cPanel (if you have FTP that should do as well)
- Find your active theme's `functions.php` file. It would usually be in the folder `wp-content/themes/your_active_theme/`.
- Edit this file (if you use FTP, you may want to download and then edit using your favorite editor) and add `wp_set_password('new_password',1);` just after the first `<?php` line, replacing `new_password` with the actual new password you'd want to setup.
- Save this file (if you use FTP, upload this file to the original location) and you would be able to login to your site
- Once you are able to log in to this site, *please remove the line that was just added*.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.