# Changed my email. Locked out

Tags: email, password

I changed my email address and don't have the original password.  When I try to reset my password it looks like Wordpress is sending the link to my old defunct email account which doesn't exist anymore.  How do I set up a new login so I can access my blogs?  Help!

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to WPSE. Do you have access to the Database and/or the files of your blog via FTP? If so have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47546/reseting-admin-password-through-phpmyadmin-fails

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database, through phpMyAdmin or otherwise, you can change the email address in the 'wp_users' table. (your table may have a different prefix)